# Веб прокси сервер наподобие https://translate.yandex.ru/ , замена iframe

Tags: php, proxy, iframe, google-translate

Помогите, пожалуйста, все уже перерыл, но не могу найти хоть что то похожее, возможно не туда копаю.

Хочу сделать веб сайт, на котором можно будет открываться интерфейс другого сайта. Но так, чтобы в адресной строке отображался сперва домен первого сайта, потом домен второго.
Пытался делать с iframe, но он открывает страницу отдельным запросом.

Очень похожее сделано в переводчике яндекса (https://translate.yandex.ru/) - если вбить в переводчик
ссылку1 (https://**ru.stackoverflow.com**/), тогда откроется
ссылка2 (hhttps://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/tt-ru.ru.a980fde4-64b6befc-cf4e49a4-74722d776562/https/**ru.stackoverflow.com**/)
это как раз то, что нужно. Прям идеальный вариант, но не очень понятно как перенаправлять запрос таким образом.

Думал парсить страницу и выводить пользователю, но тогда, если нажать на какую-нибудь ссылку внутри спарсенной страницы, тебя отправляет на оригинальную страницу. Также придется сохранять каждую страницу, которую посетит пользователь, что выглядит не очень практично.

Comment: Просто не очень представляю, каким образом спарсенный сайт доступен на  translated.turbopages.org в виде обычного каталога stackoverflow.com. Думал, он каким то образом просто пересылылает страницу и в этот момент изменяет адрес страницы.
Неужели каждый раз, когда пользователь проходит по ссылке, реально создается отдельный каталог stackoverflow.com на сервере, и в этот каталог сохраняется спарсенная страница?